# Draw a text underneath a circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm drawing a circle using html5 canvas and js.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById(key);
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 35;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fill();
context.stroke();
```

I also want to draw a text right underneath it. I tried this:

```
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.font = "bold 11";
    context.textBaseline = "top";
    context.fillText('Hello', 100-radius/4 ,100-radius/2);
```

But it was drawn in the **right**-bottom corner for some reason, whereas I wanted exactly under the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `textAlign` to center, then *add* radius to y position:

```
var spacing = 5;
context.textAlign = "center";
context.textBaseline = "top";
context.fillText('Hello', centerX, centerY + radius + spacing);
```

Comment: And how do I add a space between the circle and the text?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp just add the space value to the mix centerY + radius + space

Answer (score 0):

Your text alignment and coordinates for the text are wrong.

```
var margin = 10; // Increase the margin add space between Circle & text
context.textBaseline = "top";
context.textAlign = "center";
context.fillText('Hello', centerX , centerY + radius + margin);
```

[JSFiddle with desired outcome](http://jsfiddle.net/k8zutxaf/)